# 1970s Sci-Fi Short Story Re: Sublime Ecstasy Machine

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

1970s short story about a machine that user enters to experience ultimate, sublime ecstasy, but there’s a price. Each time, a limb or other body part is replaced with metal and machinery. Was in a paperback collection that I read in early 1980s. Could have been by Robert A. Heinlein, Philip K. Dick, or Harlan Ellison...not sure. The protagonist tries to resist going into the machine because he knows it will destroy him, part by part. His humanity, maybe his life will be lost. But the ultra-orgasmic experience is too compelling, and he can't resist.

Comment: So...not _[Sleeper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sleeper_(1973_film))_.